# Windows WMI change the value of MotherBoard SerialNumber

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

Is it possible to change the Motherboard `serialNumber` value with WMI?

```
$SN = Get-WmiObject Win32_BaseBoard
$SN.SerialNumber="123456"
$SN.put()
$SN.SerialNumber
```

The error I got was:

```
Exception calling "Put" with "0" argument(s): "Provider is not capable of the attempted operation "
```

Comment: Did it work?  Did you get an error message?

Comment: @MikeShepard won't work this is the error message`Exception calling "Put" with "0" argument(s): "Provider is not capable of the attempted operation "`

Comment: That kind of information belongs in the post, not the comments.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short no. I wouldnt expect that to work. The properties of `Win32_BaseBoard` are read-only as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394072(v=vs.85).aspx)

> SerialNumber
>
> Data type: string
>
> Access type: **Read-only**

Assuming your BIOS supports it, in most cases, you would have to change it there. That's what i did for some old dells boards to keep our inventory in check.

Comment: thanks for you answer, but is there a way to bypass the Read-only access

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAljehani the only solution that I am aware of is part of my updated question.