# Get unique Hardware id from PC

Tags: vb.net, cmd, command-prompt, vb.net-2010

I tried getting **Hard disk and Motherboard Serial Number** from my PC. It works good in Windows 7 and Above

But same code in CMD does not working for Windows XP. It Shows O.E.M to be filled or Returns Nothing

```
wmic diskdrive get name,serialnumber,model // This is cmd to get serial num
```

In Windows XP It Returns Error for serialnumber

```
wmic baseboard get product,Manufacturer,version,serialnumber // This is cmd to get MotherBoard serialnumber
```

In Windows XP and Win 8  it **returns** in serialnumber Error like "**To be filled by O.E.M**"

Am looking for Best Pc Unique Id , which can return id or serialnumber for any OS and should be unique..

Please help me

Thank You.

Comment: What do you need it for? Is this for a licensing feature, or just a unique client ID? Does it need to be consistent across OS upgrades or wipes? Does it need to be tamper-proof?

Answer (score 10):

I found a little project online where they get:

- Processor ID
- Motherboard ID
- Volume serial ID
- Mac address ID

They then hash it through **MD5** but it is depreciated now so best bet is do the same and hash it through **Sha512**

First you'll need to import and reference if not done automatically:

```
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text
```

Then the function get HWID (HardwareID)

```
Public Function Get_HWID() As String
    'Information Handler
    Dim hw As New clsComputerInfo
    'Decalre variables
    Dim hdd, cpu, mb, mac As String
    'Get all the values
    cpu = hw.GetProcessorId()
    hdd = hw.GetVolumeSerial("C")
    mb = hw.GetMotherBoardID()
    mac = hw.GetMACAddress()
    'Generate the hash
    Dim hwid As String = GenerateSHA512String(cpu & hdd & mb & mac)
    Return hwid
End Function
```

Function to generate Hash:

```
Public Shared Function GenerateSHA512String(ByVal inputString) As String
    Dim sha512 As SHA512 = SHA512Managed.Create()
    Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString)
    Dim hash As Byte() = sha512.ComputeHash(bytes)
    Dim stringBuilder As New StringBuilder()
    For i As Integer = 0 To hash.Length - 1
        stringBuilder.Append(hash(i).ToString("X2"))
    Next
    Return stringBuilder.ToString()
End Function
```

And finally Class to get the information:

```
Public Class clsComputerInfo
    Friend Function GetProcessorId() As String
        Dim strProcessorId As String = String.Empty
        Dim query As New SelectQuery("Win32_processor")
        Dim search As New ManagementObjectSearcher(query)
        Dim info As ManagementObject
        For Each info In search.Get()
            strProcessorId = info("processorId").ToString()
        Next
        Return strProcessorId
    End Function
    Friend Function GetMACAddress() As String
        Dim mc As ManagementClass = New ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
        Dim moc As ManagementObjectCollection = mc.GetInstances()
        Dim MACAddress As String = String.Empty
        For Each mo As ManagementObject In moc
            If (MACAddress.Equals(String.Empty)) Then
                If CBool(mo("IPEnabled")) Then MACAddress = mo("MacAddress").ToString()
                mo.Dispose()
            End If
            MACAddress = MACAddress.Replace(":", String.Empty)
        Next
        Return MACAddress
    End Function
    Friend Function GetVolumeSerial(Optional ByVal strDriveLetter As String = "C") As String
        Dim disk As ManagementObject = New ManagementObject(String.Format("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=""{0}:""", strDriveLetter))
        disk.Get()
        Return disk("VolumeSerialNumber").ToString()
    End Function
    Friend Function GetMotherBoardID() As String
        Dim strMotherBoardID As String = String.Empty
        Dim query As New SelectQuery("Win32_BaseBoard")
        Dim search As New ManagementObjectSearcher(query)
        Dim info As ManagementObject
        For Each info In search.Get()
            strMotherBoardID = info("SerialNumber").ToString()
        Next
        Return strMotherBoardID
    End Function
End Class
```

I reviewed the code of [this project](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?713303-VB-net-Get-computer-Hardware-ID-and-convert-to-MD5-hash)

Hope this can help you and please remember add the reference to **Management**

**More Information:**

Most common IDs used for HWID are: **CPU ID** and **MAC address based hardware ID** and **Hard Drive serial number**

HWID are not recommended as a licencing system as it isn't accurate and not practical if the user changes computer or formats the drives etc. It is more recommended to use a certificate system or more complex authentification.

Comment: Tried Your Code ... Processor Id is common on some PC..... So it Failed , for mac address PC need Network adapter , so it failed  , when i tried for getting motherboard serialnumber........it not works in win 8

Comment: Did you **add the reference**.... and you don't understand here we combine all the values in one ID because no computer will have the 4 values added together the same .... I'm on windows 8 and it works fine. Try to understand the code instead of **copy pasting**

Comment: Did you try to run your app as lower framework than 4.5 by a framework supported by XP... max XP supports is 4.0 and some don't go higher than 3.5

Comment: That unique id should not change dude .... if i format the system C: Volume serial number would change .... so the code might change next time...... so if i combine all these serial number.... c: volume serial number value may change at formatting and could change entire hwid next time....

Comment: dude in deployment place we dont have network adapter in PC , so it will return null and in XP Motherboard serialnumber not works..... and processor id returns common id in some systems......

Comment: @ramnainar you actually can get much info from motherboard in XP: [Video to teach you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fK-jKWSDhrA) Furthermore most software companies don't use HWID as it is not reliable. the mostly used HWID are: **CPU ID** and **MAC address based hardware ID** and **Hard Drive serial number** you should think of creating a proper licencing system instead of something wobbly. and why bother having a HWID if you don't have a network car to communicate to a server.

Answer (score 3):

Remember **Mac address** and **Volume serial** can be change. Hence hardware will have unpredictable changes.
So use **Processor** and **Motherboard** ID so that **hardware ID** never changes.
So on these basis, you could modify @Mederic code as below:

```
'Get the MotherBoard ID
    Function GetMotherBoardID() As String
        Dim query As New SelectQuery("Win32_BaseBoard")
        Dim search As New ManagementObjectSearcher(query)
        For Each info As ManagementObject In search.Get()
            Return info("SerialNumber").ToString()
        Next
    End Function

'Get the Processor ID 
    Function GetProcessorId() As String
        Dim query As New SelectQuery("Win32_processor")
        Dim search As New ManagementObjectSearcher(query)
        Dim info As ManagementObject
        For Each info In search.Get()
            Return info("processorId").ToString()
        Next
    End Function

' Generate Hash  
    Function GenerateHash(ByVal input As String) As String
        Dim hash = New SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input))
        Return String.Concat(hash.[Select](Function(b) b.ToString("x2")))
    End Function


'Now display Hardware ID
MessageBox.Show(GenerateHash(GetMotherBoardID() & GetProcessorId()))
```

Source code : [Code file](https://github.com/footballs/HardwareID/blob/main/HardwareID/HardwareID.vb), [Binary executable](https://github.com/footballs/HardwareID/blob/main/HardwareID/bin/Debug/HardwareID.exe).
**Processor ID** not Unique for all computers but remain unchanged. [refernce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101772/win32-processoris-processorid-unique-for-all-computers) 
**Motherboard ID** can't be changed. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678153/windows-wmi-change-the-value-of-motherboard-serialnumber)